# using two iterators in one ArrayList

Tags: java, iterator

Edit: Thank you for all your prompt replies. Now I see the assignment won't work. From another thread I read that iterator in Java is much less powerful than iterator in C++. May I ask then why use iterator in Java? Just to replace "for" loop? Thanks.

Some notes:

- The second iterator should start from the position befind the first iterator.
- I try to go through an ordered list starts form the beginning, find some objects down the list which has similar properties as the one pointed by aItr.

I don't mind using two "for" loops, but I know Java is very powerful with all those libraries. I'm just curious if there is any better methods than two "for" loops. Thanks.

Hi,

I've been using C++ but I'm new to Java so please bear with me. I try to loop through an ArrayList with two iterators. The first iterator goes through the list, and the second starts from the position pointed by the first iterator and goes till the end of the list. The following code is what I want to do (maybe invalid though):

```
.......; //initialize aList here ......
Iterator aItr = aList.iterator();
while(aItr.hasNext()){
     int a = aItr.next();
     Iterator bItr = aItr; //-----> is it valid? Any bad consequence?
     while (bItr.hasNext()){
         ............; //do stuff
     }
}
```

Is it valid to assign one iterator to another? If not, then what is the best way to do what I want to do? Thank you.

I know it's valid in C++ but not sure about Java, and I googled a lot but all the results use iterator just to print something. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Where should second iterator point after creation - at first position or after first's point position?

Comment: As was mentioned below, this doesn't do what you want it to do. Perhaps you can share what you mean to accomplish so that a better way could be found?

Comment: yock: Thank you. I edit the post to describe what I really want to do.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You shouldn't do:

```
Iterator bIter = aIter;
```

Because there is no copy constructor etc in Java; bIter will be a reference to the same underlying iterator.

You *could* use a ListIterator this way:

```
ListIterator aItr = aList.listIterator();
while (aItr.hasNext()) {
 int a = aItr.next();
 ListIterator bItr = aList.listIterator(aItr.previousIndex());
 while (bItr.hasNext()) {
   // ...
 }
}
```

But If you are thinking that ListIterator should have had a copy() method or something along those lines, I agree with you...

Comment: Thank you! You are right. I didn't find copy constructor for iterator in Java. That's why I'm confused because it limit the use of iterator. So in Java, do people use iterator just to replace for loop? Shall I just use two for loop to get what I want? Thank you.

Comment: In Java, one uses an Iterator when you don't want to know about the underlying Collection implementation. With Java 5 onwards, Iterator is used less (explicitly), because of the for-each construct, that uses Iterable and Iterator underneath. In Java 5, Iterator is mostly used when you want to iterate and conditionally remove elements.

Comment: Thank you. If I want to bItr point to the next object, the I guess should use nextIndex(). Will that cause any out of range issue? Do I need to check before I use nextIndex? Thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately if in the second while you call bItr.remove() you will get ConcurrentModificationException, in my case this is quite sad.

Answer (score 5):

If you want a second list iterator at position n in the list then use [List#listIterator(int index)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/List.html#listIterator%28int%29):

```
ListIterator bIter = list.listIterator(n);
```

Comment: Thank you! May I ask how can I get the "n"(index) from the first iterator? If it's in C++, I can use "aIter - aList.beginning()". Is that something I can do in Java?

Comment: Please look at this Javadoc for ListIterator: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html There are 2 methods nextIndex() and previousIndex() that will give you index from your first ListIterator.

Answer (score 2):

Since you seem to be using lists, the simplest solution in your case is to use two indexes, something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < aList.size(); i++) {
  for (int j = i; j < aList.size(); j++) {
    // do stuff with aList's elements
    aList.get(j);
  }
}
```

With iterators, you can achieve similar things, but you have to construct new iterators for the inner loop, possibly from

```
aList.subList(i, aList.size()).iterator();
```

Answer (score 2):

It's valid, but it won't do what you want it to do. You'll still have only one iterator, and the outer loop will terminate after the inner one has terminated for the first time.

Java iterators cannot be copied meaningfully. You'll have to use a simple for loop that increments indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
ArrayList<String> aList = new ArrayList<String>();
// do something to fill the list
for (int i = 0; i < aList.size(); i++)
{
  ArrayList<String> bList = aList.subList(i, aList.size());
  for (int j = 0; j < bList.size(); j++)
  {
    // do stuff with the sublist
  }
}
```

It's important to note that bList is backed by aList so changes to bList will be reflected in aList...make non-structural changes only to keep your sanity.