# Arraylist remove elements

Tags: java

I have a java code where i have an ArrayList and want to remove element from the arraylist.

```
   ArrayList <word> wordlist=new ArrayList<>();

   public void removeWord(String inputWord){    
        for(word z:wordlist){               
            if(z.getWord() == inputWord)
                wordlist.remove(inputWord);
            System.out.println("the word" +inputWord+ "is removed");
        }
        System.out.println(wordlist.size());
    }
```

the problem is that the element is not getting removed from the list.

Comment: And in addition to Rohit's answer, "==" sigh .equals

Answer (score 5):

You cannot remove the elements from the list you are iterating upon, using `enhanced for-loop`. This will apparently work sometimes, but not always, and will throw `ConcurrentModificationException`.

If you want to remove the elements while you iterate, you would have to use [`Iterator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html), which has method [`Iterator#remove`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove%28%29) which you can use to remove the current element.

See this tutorial: - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/collection.html to understand how to use `iterators`.

Also, as others have already mentioned, you should use [`Object#equals`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) method to compare the contents of your strings. Using `==` you don't compare the contents, rather you are comparing the reference.

Comment: Also see [`ListIterator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html) for even more options for altering the list during iteration. (See [`List.listIterator()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#listIterator%28%29)).

Comment: Thank you,as i am new to java i don't know much about Iterator, that means that i have to implement Iterator and use the remove method. But how do i use the remove method,i mean what should be condition in the method?

Comment: @coolmego. See the tutorial link I have given. It explains how to use iterators.

Comment: @coolmego. You can use [`Iterator#next`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#next%28%29) method to get the next element. Also, as Duncan mentioned, you can better use `ListIterator`. It has method [`ListIterator#next`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html#next%28%29) which gives you the next element in the list it is iterating upon.

Comment: @coolmego. Also see [`this`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6126763/using-two-iterators-in-one-arraylist), [`this`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8174964/java-using-iterator-to-search-an-arraylist-and-delete-matching-objects) and [`this`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8892027/remove-entries-from-the-list-using-iterator) post for some examples.

Comment: @coolmego. Remember to accept this as an answer. by clicking the arrow besides it.

Answer (score 1):

Use `z.getWord().equals(inputWord)` to compare Strings, and read Rohit's answer!

Answer (score 0):

In this case you need to add a "break" statement.

```
public void removeWord(String inputWord)
{
    for (Word z : wordlist) {
        if (z.getWord().equals(inputWord)) {
            wordlist.remove(z);
            System.out.println("the word" + inputWord + "is removed");
            break;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(wordlist.size());

}
```

You need to remove word obj from list since list is created for word object. Also use braces for if else statement, that is best code practice.

Answer (score 0):

### Reason?

Iterators returned by [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) is `fail-fast` in nature.

> The iterators returned by this class's iterator and `listIterator` methods are `fail-fas`t: if the list is structurally modified at any time after the iterator is created, in any way except through the iterator's own remove or add methods, the iterator will throw a `ConcurrentModificationException`. Thus, in the face of concurrent modification, the iterator fails quickly and cleanly, rather than risking arbitrary, non-deterministic behavior at an undetermined time in the future.

### Where does this iterator Come from while I am not using it?

For enhanced for loop for collections `Iterator` gets used so you can not call remove method while you are iterating.

So your loop is same as below

```
for (Iterator<word> i = c.iterator(); i.hasNext(); ){
```

### What is the Solution Then ?

You can call `iterator.remove();` and change loop based on iterator explicitly rather than implicitly.

```
    String inputWord = "john";
    ArrayList<String> wordlist = new ArrayList<String>();
    wordlist.add("rambo");
    wordlist.add("john");
    for (ListIterator<String> iterator = wordlist.listIterator(); iterator
            .hasNext();) {
        String z = iterator.next();
        if (z.equals(inputWord)) {
            iterator.remove();
            System.out.println("the word" + inputWord + "is removed");
        }
    }
    System.out.println(wordlist.size());
```

### Now Where Can I Read more?

1. [The For-Each Loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html)
2. [ArrayList Java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)